# transform data columns to rows in mySQl

Tags: mysql, transform, pivot

I have been searching and reading and haven't quite fount what I need.

table

```
name,stuff1, stuff2, skill1, skill2, skill3 ... skill200
```

196 rows in the table. Values for skills range from 0-4.

I know, not normalized. For now it needs to stay this way.

I need to return

```
       Name1,       name2,       name3,       ...
skill1 skill1value, Skill1value, skill1value, ...
skill2 skill2value, skill2value, skill2value, ...
```

each name only has one row, ever.

In other words, have a column per name and a row per skill (the value of that skill) with a where clause - where stuff = 'something'. I do not need to do every skill, only about 10-15 of the 200 or so columns.

This is mySQL. only 196 rows

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried so far? Sometimes it helps to share your attempts, even if they failed. Others here might be able to take it from there, make corrections, add stuff, and then make it work..

Comment: Different things, like unions per skill, etc. I'm going to collect us some failures I suppose.

Comment: SELECT
  skill1 as skill1,
  max( CASE name WHEN 'name1' THEN skill1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'name1',
  max( CASE name WHEN 'name2' THEN skill1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'name2'
FROM skills_table GROUP BY 1;                 --Well that gave me a row for possible values, its close but if I did get it to roll up it has some issues. 1) it would need to be a union per skill and hard coded names for columns. I could probably live with it if I could get it to roll-up correctly (one row, not 6)

Comment: Hmmn.. i can think of maybe dynamic sql or cursors but those aren't efficient solutions.. perhaps you can post some real data so I can have a better image?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly you need to join this table with it self for each column/skill you need. Not pretty but I think it's the only way in MySQL. Something like:

```
select s1.skill1, s2.skill2, s3.skill3...
  from skills s1
  join skills s2 using (name)
  join skills s3 using (name)
 ....
```

Comment: That gives me the skills as columns. I need the skills as rows and each column as a name.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try an help me tho! :)